# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Each client connection may only be authenticated once

Tags: python, celery, scheduled-tasks, pymongo

We have microservices, which are connected using grpc server and the tasks are run through our own task manager which uses celery and rabbitmq

I ran celery -A celery_worker.celery worker -B --loglevel=info and then I hit an API which triggered the task and then I got this error in my celery terminal

```
2023-06-14 18:12:26,354: INFO/Beat] beat: Starting...
[2023-06-14 18:31:01,307: INFO/MainProcess] Task FORM TASK[370daa0e-8ea1-4360-b9a6-577c2cbe4b33] received
[2023-06-14 18:31:01,309: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] post_data
[2023-06-14 18:31:01,309: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] 

[2023-06-14 18:31:01,309: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] {'user_id': '61de985e7d52db7fae60e64d', 'uri': '/forms/v3/?_id=61a7a7a864c16d20c36ca717', 'recommendation_tags': "['health-recommendations']", 'user_response': '{\n\t\t"insurance-params1": {\n\t\t\t"question_set_id": "61de72f707de8c03e5dbba1b",\n\t\t\t"user_response": {\n\t\t\t\t"61dd673a7f210c3947dbba1c": [\n\t\t\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"Self": "36"\n\t\t\t\t\t}\n\t\t\t\t],\n\t\t\t\t"61dd9f747f210c3947dbba1d": "400001",\n\t\t\t\t"61de65abe0f9b88032dbba1b": "5 - 10 Lakhs",\n\t\t\t\t"61de6717613bcb8f02dbba1b": "Vanshdeep Pradhan",\n\t\t\t\t"61de673a613bcb8f02dbba1c": "9876543210",\n\t\t\t\t"61de71787774308058dbba1b": "Male",\n\t\t\t\t"61de7218ec0d252d77dbba21": "5 - 10 Lakhs"\n\t\t\t}\n\t\t},\n\t\t"lead-health2": {\n\t\t\t"question_set_id": "605323f8150d72fc6ee7c474",\n\t\t\t"user_response": {}\n\t\t}\n\t}', 'token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJmb3JtX2lkIjoiNjFhN2E3YTg2NGMxNmQyMGMzNmNhNzE3IiwidXNlcl9pZCI6IjYxZGU5ODVlN2Q1MmRiN2ZhZTYwZTY0ZCIsImNkIjoiMjAyMi0xMi0yMyAwNDowMjoxMS40NjMzNjIifQ.Zu9B30raaBJ0-naYAuvVcqWnY4TBivxVveJJ7TyFY80'}
[2023-06-14 18:31:01,309: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] 

[2023-06-14 18:31:01,366: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] /home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py:657: RuntimeWarning: Exception raised outside body: OperationFailure("Each client connection may only be authenticated once. Previously authenticated as: oneassure-admin@admin, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Each client connection may only be authenticated once. Previously authenticated as: oneassure-admin@admin', 'code': 5626701, 'codeName': 'Location5626701'}"):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/forms/views.py", line 65, in form_post
    self.update_state(state='PENDING',
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 971, in update_state
    self.backend.store_result(
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 482, in store_result
    self._store_result(task_id, result, state, traceback,
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/mongodb.py", line 190, in _store_result
    self.collection.replace_one({'_id': task_id}, meta, upsert=True)
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 29, in __get__
    return super().__get__(instance, owner)
  File "/home/devdcodes/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/functools.py", line 967, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/mongodb.py", line 290, in collection
    collection = self.database[self.taskmeta_collection]
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/objects.py", line 29, in __get__
    return super().__get__(instance, owner)
  File "/home/devdcodes/.pyenv/versions/3.8.10/lib/python3.8/functools.py", line 967, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/mongodb.py", line 285, in database
    return self._get_database()
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/mongodb.py", line 274, in _get_database
    if not db.authenticate(self.user, self.password, source=source):
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 1492, in authenticate
    self.client._cache_credentials(
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 781, in _cache_credentials
    sock_info.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 810, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 673, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 589, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram(credentials, sock_info, 'SCRAM-SHA-256')
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 333, in _authenticate_scram
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 683, in command
    return command(self, dbname, spec, slave_ok,
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 159, in command
    helpers._check_command_response(
  File "/home/devdcodes/OneAssure/oneassure-task-manager/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 164, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(errmsg, code, response, max_wire_version)
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Each client connection may only be authenticated once. Previously authenticated as: oneassure-admin@admin, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Each client connection may only be authenticated once. Previously authenticated as: oneassure-admin@admin', 'code': 5626701, 'codeName': 'Location5626701'}
```

I tried checking my authentication details and also restarting the celery terminal
I expected the task to be executed without error